# Are quote line items automatically created when inserting a quote in apex

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, quote, quotelineitem

I was reading [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sales_admin_products_quotes_contracts/units/sales_admin_products_quotes_contracts_unit_2) and it says quote lines are automatically created from the opportunity products when a quote is created.

> At this point, he selects the quote, and he sees that the product from the opportunity appears as a line item. Lance can add other products as line items if he wants to.

Does this work the same in apex when inserting a quote with a related Opportunity with Line Items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not. In Apex, you need to explicitly create and insert the `QuoteLineItem` objects you want, providing the `QuoteId` and `PricebookEntryId` lookup values and the `Quantity` and `UnitPrice`.